# Étymologie de "grand huit"?

Tags: étymologie, jeux

Je lisais récemment un article qui faisait référence à un « *grand huit* », qui semble avoir le sens « *roller coaster* » en anglais.
La traduction littérale est « *great eight* », mais comment en est-on venu à cette signification ?

Comment: Wiki: "Ces petits trains américains seront peut-être l'une des explications pour laquelle l'appellation américaine ou anglaise littérale traduite n'est pas celle du support, "Russian Mountains", mais celle du véhicule : "Roller Coaster" ("Rouleau de cabotage"), et l'expression allemande non pas "Russischen Bergen", mais "Achterbahn" ("Train en huit", se rapprochant de l'autre appellation de "Grand huit", qui devrait théoriquement se justifier uniquement si des loopings de forme proche d'un "8" y figurent).", pas toujours fiable, mais bon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« *Roller coaster* » se traduit généralement par « [grand huit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grand_huit) » ou « [montagnes russes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/montagnes_russes) ».

Ces deux noms découlent d'une analogie.

Pour « grand huit », cela tient au fait que [le circuit est un ruban](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/_huit/40590/locution) se croisant parfois, reproduisant grossièrement un 8 d'après une vue aérienne. Des circuits portant la qualification de [*Figure 8*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_8_(montagnes_russes)) (dont le circuit ressemblait réellement à un 8 en vue aérienne) sont peut-être à l'origine de la dénomination française, par extension du nom original.

D'après [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montagnes_russes#Appellation_selon_les_pays) (merci à [Larme](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3016/larme) pour la référence), la forme de huit ne devrait se justifier que si des loopings en forme de huit sont présents. Aucune source externe n'est citée sur ce point, il apparaît donc difficile de trancher entre les deux interprétations du nom.

Concernant « montagnes russes », la locution traduit l'histoire des manèges de ce type :

> Le concept de « montagnes russes » vient des courses de luges se déroulant sur des collines de neige spécialement construites pour celles-ci, particulièrement dans les environs de Saint-Pétersbourg.
>
> À la fin des années 1700, leur popularité est telle que des entrepreneurs commencent à copier l'idée ailleurs, en utilisant des voitures munies de roues attachées sur des voies. Une compagnie, *Les Montagnes russes* à Belleville, construit et s'occupe de montagnes russes à Paris, en 1812.
>   <sub>— Source : [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montagnes_russes#Luges_puis_chariots_sur_collines)</sub>

---

<sub>Merci à [Divulgâchames](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3177/divulg%C3%A2ch%C3%A2mes) pour la référence Larousse et [Yohann V.](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7142/yohann-v) pour l'histoire de « montagnes russes ».</sub>

Comment: Je suppose que la formation "8" est à la vue de l'oeil d'un oiseau, pas de l'oeil d'un humain debout?

Comment: @Jez Dans ma compréhension personnelle, oui. J'ai d'ailleurs trouvé un type de montagnes russes qualifiés de _Figure 8_, dont le circuit est un 8 en vue aérienne. J'ai intégré cette information et divers commentaires à la réponse.

Comment: @Chop [Voici](http://www.lesaviezvous.net/loisirs/jeux/origine-des-montagnes-russes.html) pour les montagnes russes. Et l'article [wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montagnes_russes) : *"Le concept de « montagnes russes » vient des courses de luges se déroulant sur des collines de neige spécialement construites pour celles-ci, particulièrement dans les environs de Saint-Pétersbourg"* ! ;)